Input devices taking a long time to work for login screen
I recently installed KDE-plasma on my arch system, and I am having an extremely annoying problem. Whenever I reboot, grub recognizes my keyboard input instantly, but when it gets to the login screen it takes about a minute for the keyboard and mouse input to start working. My keyboard and mouse are connected by usb. With the guidance of chatgpt, I wrote a script that resets my usb devices:
#!/usr/bin/env fish
for device in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/authorized
        echo "0" > $device
        echo "1" > $device
end

sudo modprobe -r usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid

This script causes the keyboard and mouse to disconnect and not work for seemingly the same ammount of time they don't work on the login screen. When I run `sudo dmesg -w' and then run my script, I get this output for dmesg while the keyboard and mouse are disconnected (except for the last two lines, which always appear right after the mouse that I am constantly wiggling starts working):
[ 1122.351839] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 1122.352350] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 1122.352353] usb 1-6.2: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 1122.352354] usb 1-6.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 19
[ 1122.397471] hid-generic 0003:258A:002A.0007: can't resubmit intr, 0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input0, status -19
[ 1122.446122] usb 1-6.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 22
[ 1122.508655] usb 1-6.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 23
[ 1123.005104] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ 1123.011062] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.011092] hub 1-0:1.0: 16 ports detected
[ 1123.013025] usb usb1: authorized to connect
[ 1123.013113] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.013133] hub 2-0:1.0: 10 ports detected
[ 1123.015936] usb usb2: authorized to connect
[ 1123.033664] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[ 1123.157732] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 1123.157738] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[ 1123.160617] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[ 1123.307087] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=048d, idProduct=5702, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1123.307101] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1123.307106] usb 1-5: Product: ITE Device
[ 1123.307111] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: ITE Tech. Inc.
[ 1123.312456] hid-generic 0003:048D:5702.0009: hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.12 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
[ 1123.434053] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[ 1123.576378] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=60.90
[ 1123.576393] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1123.576398] usb 1-6: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 1123.578778] hub 1-6:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.579142] hub 1-6:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1123.703990] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[ 1123.845829] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=60.90
[ 1123.845843] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1123.845848] usb 1-11: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 1123.847794] hub 1-11:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1123.848087] hub 1-11:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1123.920599] usb 1-6.2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
[ 1124.010984] usb 1-6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0801, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1124.010998] usb 1-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1124.011004] usb 1-6.2: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[ 1124.012134] hub 1-6.2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1124.012188] hub 1-6.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1124.133932] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
[ 1129.264313] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1144.836750] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1145.339852] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[ 1150.596409] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1166.172638] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1166.279184] usb usb1-port14: attempt power cycle
[ 1166.355609] usb 1-6.2.2: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[ 1166.476391] usb 1-6.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=328f, idProduct=003f, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 1166.476402] usb 1-6.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 1166.476407] usb 1-6.2.2: Product: HD Webcam eMeet C960
[ 1166.476410] usb 1-6.2.2: Manufacturer: EMEET
[ 1166.476413] usb 1-6.2.2: SerialNumber: SN0001
[ 1166.480157] usb 1-6.2.2: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Webcam eMeet C960 (328f:003f)
[ 1166.482505] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 5 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[ 1166.482631] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 12 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 1).
[ 1166.490822] input: HD Webcam eMeet C960: HD Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.2/1-6.2.2:1.0/input/input30
[ 1166.495908] usb 1-6.2.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 1166.782194] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[ 1171.805560] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1177.138570] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1177.345219] usb 1-14: device not accepting address 31, error -62
[ 1177.745157] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[ 1182.898412] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1188.231524] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1188.438055] usb 1-14: device not accepting address 32, error -62
[ 1188.438357] usb usb1-port14: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 1188.528072] usb 1-6.2.3: new low-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[ 1188.642930] usb 1-6.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c077, bcdDevice=72.00
[ 1188.642946] usb 1-6.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1188.642951] usb 1-6.2.3: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[ 1188.642955] usb 1-6.2.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1188.648293] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.3/1-6.2.3:1.0/0003:046D:C077.000A/input/input31
[ 1188.648735] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.3/input0
[ 1188.741319] usb 1-6.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[ 1188.851937] usb 1-6.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=258a, idProduct=002a, bcdDevice=10.39
[ 1188.851952] usb 1-6.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1188.851957] usb 1-6.2.4: Product: Gaming KB 
[ 1188.851960] usb 1-6.2.4: Manufacturer: SINO WEALTH
[ 1188.859498] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.0/0003:258A:002A.000B/input/input32
[ 1189.062197] hid-generic 0003:258A:002A.000B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [SINO WEALTH Gaming KB ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input0
[ 1189.065075] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.1/0003:258A:002A.000C/input/input33
[ 1189.125064] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.1/0003:258A:002A.000C/input/input34
[ 1189.125270] input: SINO WEALTH Gaming KB  Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2.4/1-6.2.4:1.1/0003:258A:002A.000C/input/input35
[ 1189.125768] hid-generic 0003:258A:002A.000C: input,hiddev97,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [SINO WEALTH Gaming KB ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2.4/input1
[ 1189.292728] usb 1-6.2.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 1189.297446] usb 1-6.2.2: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 1190.179103] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 12 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 3).
[ 1190.181524] usb 1-6.2.2: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 12 on unit 1: 0 (exp. 3).

Notice how after [ 1129.264313] it starts to give some errors with the code -110. It spent a long time on these, so I think these errors are causing much of the delay. Also, at [ 1171.805560] the lines that include the word "timeout" also took a long time. If I could fix these errors and prevent these timeouts, I think that would remove a significant amount of the delay.
I have tried adding this line to grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
I tried switching the environment to xorg instead of wayland on the login screen and rebooting, I have tried linux-lts, I tried changing the bios setting for uhci handoff to disabled, switching display managers, plugging into every usb port my computer has, disabling autosuspend in grub, and creating a file called /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules with the line:
ACTION="add, SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="258a", ATTR{idProduct}=="002a", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="on"

and none of it has helped at all.


Do you have a special keyboard where separate iCUE software can still be installed?
2.Are the mouse and keyboard connected to an adapter/hub?
Have you tried other USB ports?
Try starting the computer once with only the mouse and once with only the keyboard to see if it still happens.


Why did the need arise to get ChatGPT to write said script?

I tried rebooting once without the mouse and once without the keyboard. I have already tried every usb port on my computer.  I don't see how my keyboard having a seperate iCUE software could be causing a problem since it still happens with only the mouse (Its a basic mouse and I very much doubt there is special software for it) I am not using an adapter or hub. I am plugging these devices into the ports that came attatched to the motherboard that stick out of the back of the case.

So the Mouse is he Problem If the Keyboard works alone?

The problem happens when I have only the mouse plugged in and when I have only the keyboard plugged in.

What i would try is a different Mouse and Keyboard and after try to start a Debian or Ubuntu Livesystem to Check If the Motherboard IS the Problem, If yo dont have do Changes in the config after your fresh Arch Install.

What ist your os device USB, SSD m2?

I have also recently started to face this exact issue on Arch. I am on xfce.
